# How can I test delegating methods using SimpleDelegator and RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, delegates

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and trying to make some tests with RSpec.

I have a class:

```
class A 
  def method1
    "test"
   end
end

class B < SimpleDelegator
  def initialize(events)
    @events = events 
  end
end
```

Now I'm trying to test delegation behaviour:

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe B do
  let(:a) { A.new }
  let(:b) { B.new(a) }

  it "Should delegate unknown calls to A object" do
    expect(b.method1).not_to eq(nil)
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `method1' for nil:B
```

Seems that the test would pass if add method_missing manually:

```
class B < SimpleDelegator
  def initialize(events)
    @events = events 
  end
  def method_missing(meth, *args, &blk)
    @events.send(meth, *args, &blk)
  end
end
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you added a initializer to the class B without calling super and passing the instance you want to decorate. Your code should look like this:

```
class A 
  def method1
    "test"
   end
end

class B < SimpleDelegator
  def initialize(events)
    @events = events 
    super(events)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define an `initialize` method on `B`. [`SimpleDelegator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) defines one for you. When you defined your own `initialize` method, you overrode the `initialize` method you inherited from the `SimpleDelegator` class.

Try this:

```
class A 
  def method1
    "test"
   end
end

class B < SimpleDelegator
end
```

This is from irb: `B.new(A.new).method1 #=> "test"`

You *could* define your own `initialize` method and call `super`, but I wouldn't unless you really had to.